# python : Removing list brackets from list of tuples

Tags: python

I apologise if there are dupes. I've only found codes that remove tuples from list, but not the list itself.
I have a constant

```
a = [[(1,2,3),(3,2,1)], [(2,1,6),(7,3,2),(1,0,2)]]
```

And I'd like to remove all the brackets inside `a` so it becomes

```
a = (1,2,3),(3,2,1),(2,1,6),(7,3,2),(1,0,2)
```

Is it possible to do it in a simple way?
I've tried something similar to

```
for i in a:
    print(a[0], a[1], a[2])
```

but the number of tuples in each interior list vary, so I can't just use [0] etc..

Comment: Your desired `a` isn’t valid Python syntax. You can print the elements of `a` however you like.

Comment: @barny "Your desired a isn’t valid Python syntax", mhm, how does it come no error is raised when copy-pasting it into the PYthon ?

Comment: The desired output syntax produces a tuple with 5 elements, the outer parentheses being implicit.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain

print([i for i in chain.from_iterable(a)])
```

---

```
[(1, 2, 3), (3, 2, 1), (2, 1, 6), (7, 3, 2), (1, 0, 2)]
```

Comment: Or maybe `print(",".join(str(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(a)))`, to reproduce OP's output more closely.

Comment: Or, to produce the tuple they seem to want, `a=tuple(chain.from_iterable(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to this is by using `reduce`.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda a,b : tuple(a+b),a)
((1, 2, 3), (3, 2, 1), (2, 1, 6), (7, 3, 2), (1, 0, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[(1,2,3),(3,2,1)], [(2,1,6),(7,3,2),(1,0,2)]]

for _list in a:
    for _tuple in _list:
        print(_tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension, however, you will get of list of tuples, for what you've mentioned in the desired output, you need to unpack the tuples with the same number of variables:

```
a = [x for l in a for x in l]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (3, 2, 1), (2, 1, 6), (7, 3, 2), (1, 0, 2)]
```